# Using CSS Transform Scale to match the parent element

Tags: scale, css-transforms

I have an element that needs to scale to be 100% of the parent element. Because the element contains pixel based animations with images that can scale I can't use percentages. Is there anyway to do this using css transform scale?

Comment: I guess there's a trick for preventing the problem which would happen if you use percentages. Could you please explain more? Do you want to make sure your image is not being scaled in a wrong aspect ratio or more that the quality it has?

Comment: The animation happens by using a css sprite. Any changes to that element in size would break the animation. http://spritely.net/

Comment: Could you post some code for us to try something on? [Scale is always percentual](http://jsbin.com/jojip/1/), isn't it? (in this case, it scales to 200%)

Comment: Oh, it's actually possible to implement the same thing with img that is scalable but I guess you don't want to modify the library! Gotta add it to the library in the future ;)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aV9R3/

Just wanted to post this in case anyone had a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

The relative **css transform** values are **relative to itself** (border-box). E.g some absolute centering snippet:

```
width: 100px;
height: 200px;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

In Firefox you can try some hack with your parent element:

```
background-image: -moz-element(#yourElementToScale);
background-size: contain;
```

But generally its not possible without using percentages on width/height in pure CSS. If you wanna use javascript just scale by the factors:

```
var scaleX = parentElement.offsetWidth / element.offsetWidth;
var scaleY = parentElement.offsetHeight / element.offsetHeight;
```

Apply this scale-factors as transform could look like:

```
transform: scale(scaleX, scaleY);
```